# AngularFire2/Firebase - How to submit server datetime from client?

Tags: datetime, firebase, angularfire2

I am posting an item to a table in Firebase. I want to post a datetime property but would like to be able to post a datetime that is not from the client but from the Firebase server itself. Is there a way to do this with Firebase where you can specify that when an item gets posted that Firebase will insert this date property when the item is stored?

Comment: Please post some code that you may have written.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.ServerValue